# Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.mail.host' in value "${spring.mail.host}"

Tags: spring-boot

`Bilan-application-context.xml`:

```
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="${spring.mail.host}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${spring.mail.port}"/>
<!--         <property name="username" value="howtodoinjava@gmail.com"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/> -->
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">${mail.transport.protocol}</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">${mail.smtp.auth}</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">${mail.smtp.starttls.enable}</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">${mail.debug}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

The error is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
Invalid bean definition with name 'mailSender' defined in class path resource 
[bilan-application-context.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.mail.host' in value "${spring.mail.host}"; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.mail.host' in value "${spring.mail.host}"
```

I cannot find the solution to the above.

Answer (score 1):

You present you property file inside inside `Bilan-application-context.xml` as:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:spring/mail.properties"/>
```

- notice that `mail.properties` is used in my example, you need to make sure to change it to the appropriate path and the right filename according to your properties.